# Define Outgoing/Calling Port for SOAP Web Service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx, ports

The application application I'm currently working on is required to interface with a web service using SOAP.  The service providers want to restrict access to the service via a firewall using BOTH an IP address and a Port.  I'm using VS 2010 and the service has been added as a .NET 2.0 Web Service.

Right now the firewall rule for my connection's port is set to 'ANY' and the service team wants to tighten it down to a specific port.  I can't seem to find any way to set a specific outgoing port (port used when exiting my web server) in my service.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: The app was built in .NET 4.  The service reference was added as a Web Service Reference (.NET 2.0 supported), not simply a Service Reference.

Comment: I don't actually know how to do this using a Service Reference, but it's probably easier than my answer below. Is there a reason you're using a web reference?

Comment: I'm using a Web Reference because that's how the reference was added earlier in the project.  I tried changing it to a Service Reference but that seemed to completely change the auto-generated objects.  With where we are in the dev lifecycle it will have to remain as Web Reference for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this, but it's a non-trivial customization.

1. See [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/) for the general techniques. Near the bottom, you'll find "Heavy-Duty Customization".
2. By overriding the `GetWebRequest` method, you can gain access to the `HttpWebRequest` instance being used by the request.
3. `HttpWebRequest` has a [`ServicePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.servicepoint%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property.
4. `ServicePoint` has a [BindIPEndPointDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property.
5. Set this property to point to a method that will decide which IP address and port to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried what you suggested:
`protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
  {
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
   request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(DefineIpPort);
   return request;
  }

private IPEndPoint DefineIpPort(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
  {
   return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
  }`
However, I tested the result using `netstat -ano` and it isn't using port 1234.  Seems the app is still choosing an arbitrary port.

Comment: Should I be able set a breakpoint in the extended class code?  Each time I try I get the "Breakpoint will not currently be hit..." message.  Wondering if I messed something up...

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set a breakpoint. Be careful of what namespace you created the partial class in. It has to have the same name and namespace as the original.

Comment: Had to uncheck the "Debugging=>Enable Just My Code" option for the breakpoint. Namespace is identical, confirmed by removing `partial` keyword from class definition and receiving "another partial declaration of this type exists" error.  Still can't get the app to use port 1234 for outgoing communication. :- /